# Drag and Drop in webapplication

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

Now i work on maps and canvas on web portal, I want to automate single button on Chrome.

I use F12 button to find a location of this element on canvas, I have also put HttpRequest to make connection to the server.

I have heard that there is a method called Drag and Drop to use mouse cursor to change position of each element.

It is required for my automation Framework using Webdriver and Nunit in C#.

Anyone knows how to drag element and drop to another place on canvas?

Comment: I have no idea what capabilities C# has for generating HTML, but what you're referring to is client side, therefore I would assume you want to use JavaScript to implement drag and drop? Perhaps have a read through  [The basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#The_basics) and then update your questions with where you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, first of all I need to get response/request from JSON rcp (the same what is on Chrome/F12/Network/WebSocket), then i need to create javascript files for each element what is on canvas html5, because each element has unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Go through these links explaining use of drag and drop in canvas
http://html5.litten.com/ie-compatible-canvas-drag-and-drop-with-jquery-and-excanvas/
http://html5.litten.com/moving-shapes-on-the-html5-canvas-with-the-keyboard/

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please refrain from posting link answers only. Try to summarize in your answer. If the link becomes dead then your answer will be useless.

Comment: Hi, thank You for quick response. But it should be for Selenium Webdriver Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have found code like this, maybe it will be helpfull for someone.

```
IWebElement drag = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='ac254bb9-c756-4bbe-94d2-507e72b30cbe']"));
            Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
            actions.ClickAndHold(drag).MoveByOffset(264, 438).Release(drag).Build().Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            actions.ClickAndHold(drag).MoveByOffset(200, 430).Release(drag).Build().Perform();
            Driver.SwitchTo();
```